# Actual Android device not found adb devices

Tags: android, adb, logcat, android-logcat

I have written a simple app and would like to try it out on my Samsung Galaxy i9000. After some trouble finding the proper USB-driver i finally have the device show up in the Device Manager under Android Phone/Android Composite ADB Interface. I am running Vista SP1 and my phone is a Samsung Galaxy i9000 with 2.1-update1.

The problem I'm having is when running "adb servies" in cmd the device list is empty, and the device is not showing up in Eclipse.

- The phone is in developer (debug) mode
- I have added android:debuggable="true" for the app in the manifest-file
- I have tried several times to kill and restart adb in the cmd-prompt without result
- I have rebooted both phone and computer several times
- Used usddeview to completely remove previous drives before installing the proper ones

I ran the following in the commandprompt:

- adb kill-server
- set ADB_TRACE=all
- adb nodaemon server

Then i ran Eclipse and got this (never mind the wierd sdk-path :P):

```
C:\Program Files\JCreatorV4LE\Android\android-sdk-windows\tools>adb kill-server

C:\Program Files\JCreatorV4LE\Android\android-sdk-windows\tools>set ADB_TRACE=al
l

C:\Program Files\JCreatorV4LE\Android\android-sdk-windows\tools>adb nodaemon ser
ver
bit_buffer_init 002A2780
bit_buffer_init 002A37C0
adb_socketpair: returns (100, 101)
fdevent_update: add 1 to 101
event_looper_hook: call hook for 101 (new=0, old=1)
transport: local client init
Created device thread
transport: client_socket_thread() starting
socket_loopback_server: port 5037 type tcp => fd 102
fdevent_update: add 1 to 102
event_looper_hook: call hook for 102 (new=0, old=1)
_event_socketpair_start: hook 101(pair:100) for 65 wanted=1
_event_socket_start: hooking 102(lo-server:5037) for 1 (flags 41)
adb_win32: waiting for 2 events
socket_loopback_client: could not connect to tcp:5555
socket_loopback_client: could not connect to tcp:5557
socket_loopback_client: could not connect to tcp:5559
socket_loopback_client: could not connect to tcp:5561
socket_loopback_client: could not connect to tcp:5563
socket_loopback_client: could not connect to tcp:5565
socket_loopback_client: could not connect to tcp:5567
socket_loopback_client: could not connect to tcp:5569
socket_loopback_client: could not connect to tcp:5571
socket_loopback_client: could not connect to tcp:5573
socket_loopback_client: could not connect to tcp:5575
socket_loopback_client: could not connect to tcp:5577
socket_loopback_client: could not connect to tcp:5579
socket_loopback_client: could not connect to tcp:5581
socket_loopback_client: could not connect to tcp:5583
socket_loopback_client: could not connect to tcp:5585
adb_win32: got one (index 1)
_event_socket_check 102(lo-server:5037) returns 1
adb_win32: signaling 102(lo-server:5037) for 1
adb_socket_accept on fd 102 returns fd 119
LS(1): created (fd=119)
Connecting to smart socket
Creating smart socket
SS(0): created 00407E60
fdevent_update: add 1 to 119
event_looper_hook: call hook for 119 (new=0, old=1)
SS(0): enqueue 16
SS(0): len is 12
SS(0): 'host:version'
writex: 119 0022CCA8 12: 4f4b41593030303430303161  OKAY0004001a
writex: 119 ok
SS(0): handled host service 'version'
SS(0): closed
adb_close: 119(accept:102(lo-server:5037))
LS(1): closed
_event_socketpair_start: hook 101(pair:100) for 65 wanted=1
adb_win32: waiting for 2 events
adb_win32: got one (index 1)
_event_socket_check 102(lo-server:5037) returns 0
adb_win32: waiting for 2 events
adb_win32: got one (index 1)
_event_socket_check 102(lo-server:5037) returns 1
adb_win32: signaling 102(lo-server:5037) for 1
adb_socket_accept on fd 102 returns fd 120
LS(2): created (fd=120)
Connecting to smart socket
Creating smart socket
SS(0): created 00407E60
fdevent_update: add 1 to 120
event_looper_hook: call hook for 120 (new=0, old=1)
_event_socketpair_start: hook 101(pair:100) for 65 wanted=1
_event_socket_start: hooking 120(accept:102(lo-server:5037)) for 1 (flags 41)
adb_win32: waiting for 3 events
adb_win32: got one (index 1)
_event_socket_check 102(lo-server:5037) returns 0
adb_win32: waiting for 3 events
adb_win32: got one (index 2)
_event_socket_check 120(accept:102(lo-server:5037)) returns 1
adb_win32: signaling 120(accept:102(lo-server:5037)) for 1
SS(0): enqueue 22
SS(0): len is 18
SS(0): 'host:track-devices'
device tracker 002A6D98 created
LS(0) bound to 'track-devices'
SS(0): okay
SS(0): closed
LS(2): enqueue 4
_event_socketpair_start: hook 101(pair:100) for 65 wanted=1
adb_win32: waiting for 3 events
```

This make any sense? I've spent hours trying to figure this out so any suggestion at all is appreciated.

/Johan

Comment: What kind of connection do you have between your computer and phone? I can choose four different with my HTC Desire (Recharge, HTC Sync, Disc drive, USB-tethering).

Comment: I can choose between Samsung Kies, Media player, Mass Storage, PC-internet and Ask when connected. But arent these irrelevant since I have the phone debugging-mode (Settings -> Applications -> Development) ?

Comment: I solved it! Downloaded usb-drivers from here and it solved it, works fine now: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=728929. Thanks for the help anyway, cheers!

Answer (score 5):

I had a same kind of device not detecting issue when i have updated the android sdk tools. After searching internet and referring other resources, i found that the sdk update process had replaced the **adb_usb.ini** file which is located in the **.android** folder on the **user profile** folder. Then i have added the usb driver keys for my device ( which came with the driver installer folder ) to that  adb_usb.ini file. Then i have restarted the adb server with the following commands.

***adb kill-server***

***adb start-server***

Then the device is detected and i have solved my issue. I hope this will fix your issue..

Comment: Thank you, it works fine. In addition, get driver key in Windows: open Devices Manager -> Portable Device ->right click on your device and choose Properties -> tab Detail -> choose Driver key in Property dropdown list. 

Copy this key and past in adb_usb.ini